# error 1064(42000) while trying to execute mysqldump command

Tags: sql, shell, mysql

im trying to run the following command:
**mysql> mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql;**
on my local(On my pc) Mysql 5.5 server but I keep getting this error:

```
mysql> mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
dump --all-databases > dump.sql' at line 1.
```

Answer (score 97):

mysqldump is a command you invoke at the shell prompt, not within the mysql client environment.

```
mysql> exit
$ mysqldump --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Comment: How do i get to the shell prompt? when I execute the command mysql>exit It just closes the cmd window.

Comment: [How To Open Command Prompt in Windows 7](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/a/command-prompt-windows-7.htm)

Comment: You'll also need to read [Customizing the PATH for MySQL Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-installation-windows-path.html).

Comment: I have to login to vote for you, thanks.

Answer (score 28):

You must execute that command from the system shell, don't forget to use username and password to access all databases, example:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > dump.sql
```

Comment: Thank you.  This solved my problem.

Comment: I was facing similar problem and I open command prompt as administrator. Then put the command  and its working

Comment: mysqldump -u root -p name-of-database > dump.sql    -- to dump single database thanks

Comment: Installing the `mysqldump` utility on Ubuntu can be done as shown in this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1048822/581041